# node commands working properly but npm commands not working at all

Tags: node.js, windows

I have installed both node 12 and 14 on my windows x64 pc but when I do any "npm" command it does not do anything but node commands are working .what should i do

Answer (score 0):

the problem was my cmd. it was not opening, it used to just open flash on the screen and close immediately. The solution is to delete the second object in the registry editor in this path: "Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor"